# Please fix incorrectly closed duplicates of "Reverse each individual word of Hello World string with Java"

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions

The question [Reverse each individual word of "Hello World" string with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441501/reverse-each-individual-word-of-hello-world-string-with-java) has been incorrectly used as a canonical for questions that ask about how to reverse an *entire string*.

For example, reversing the entire string `"Hello World"` looks like

```
"dlroW olleH"
```

On the other hand, reversing *each individual word* of `"Hello World"` looks like

```
"olleH dlroW"
```

**If anyone has a dupe-hammer for Java**, can you please go through [incorrectly closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2441501?lq=1), and close them as duplicates of a more appropriate canonical?

#### Examples of incorrectly closed question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780122/function-to-reverse-a-string

While you're at it, this question might either be a canonical, or needs to be closed as a duplicate of one:

- [Reverse each individual word of "Hello World" string with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441501/reverse-each-individual-word-of-hello-world-string-with-java)

Comment: [Here's a list of possible candidates that's easy enough to go over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2441501?lq=1).

Comment: [Here's something I believe is more appropriate as canonical regarding reversal of single strings.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7569335/1079354)

Comment: [Here's something I believe is appropriate as canonical regarding reversal of strings without any built-in functions, like `reverse`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2612976/1079354)